# Unique constraint violated exception: Error 301

Tags: business-intelligence, hana, amdp

I am getting Unique Constraint Violation error on direct update as well as standard ADSO while inserting 180k records. I am sure that all the records are unique for my composite primary key (Combination of 12 fields).

I am inserting the data using AMDP in platform edition.

Validated uniqueness of Records using this:

```
Select a, b, c, d from "Calculation View" group by a, b, c, d having count(*)>1
```

This query returns no rows. My ADSO does not currently have any data.

Also validated using:

```
Select Count(*) from (Select a, b, c, d from "Calculation View")
Select Count(*) from (Select distinct a, b, c, d from "Calculation View")
```

Count is same in both queries.

Here is the error:

> Error when executing the database procedure
> "ZFXX_VOLUME_REPORTING=>METH_INSERT_BMS_PIVOT". SQL error: "301". SQL
> message: "unique constraint violated:
> "SAPABAP1"."ZFXX_VOLUME_REPORTING=>METH_INSERT_BMS_PIVOT#stb2#20170616162711"":
> line 10 col 3 (at pos 253):
> "SAPABAP1"."ZFXX_VOLUME_REPORTING=>METH_INSERT_BMS_PIVOT": line 27 col
> 1 (at pos 903): [301] (range 3) unique constraint violated exception:
> unique constraint violated: TrexUpdate failed on table
> 'SAPABAP1:/BIC/AG9SC26ADU2' with error: unique constraint violation in
> self check for table SAPABAP1:/BIC/AG9SC26ADU2en,
> constraint='$trexexternalkey$',
> div='10,1030201703;6,201703;12,FR0010451260;2,20;4,FR04;6,DE1410;7,Managed;1,0;3,DIS;1,D;1,0;12,Alternatives',
> pos=195705, indexname=/BIC/AG9SC26ADU2~0, rc=55".

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same error in native HANA. And am investigating ..

Comment: Yes I did solve it. It was due to the fact that HANA was making error while comparing double spaces, such as 'Hello  World' has two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Without deeper on system analysis it's close to impossible to see what's happening here. It's likely a bug, but to verify this, SAP support will have to review the system and the problematic ADSO and data source. I highly recommend opening a support incident.